# Primefaces calendar only month and year choice not sending to bean

Tags: primefaces, calendar

I am using p:calendar for choosing only month and year.Days are not showing.But my choice is not going to the managedBean.Here is the codes;

```xml
<h:panelGroup id="editClusterStartDatePanel"
    class="datePickerYearAndMonth">
    <p:calendar id="editClusterStartDate"
        value="#{defineCommissionClusterPaymentBean.selectedClusterDate}"
        navigator="true" required="true"
        locale="#{languageBean.languageCode}" mode="inline" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

[image]

selectedClusterDate value is setting same date every time. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```xml
<p:calendar id="editClusterStartDate"
        value="#{defineCommissionClusterPaymentBean.selectedClusterDate}"
        navigator="true" required="true"
        locale="#{languageBean.languageCode}" mode="inline"
        widgetVar="myCalendar">
                <p:ajax event="viewChange" onstart="
                                var mc=PF('myCalendar');
                                var crtDate=new Date(cfg.ext.params[1].value,cfg.ext.params[0].value-1,1,0,0,0);
                                /* see calendar.js, function bindDateSelectListener*/
                                var crtDateAsS=$.datepicker.formatDate(mc.cfg.dateFormat,crtDate);
                                mc.input.val(crtDateAsS);
                                return false;" />               
</p:calendar>
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand: Is this an advise? From my point of view it fully answers the question; just check the differences between original snippet and the proposed one.

Comment: * Add the widgetVar attribute so you can obtain a reference to it in JavaScript.  
* Add the ajax event that captures Year/Month changes and updates the associated input (a hidden field that will be posted on form submit).

Comment: It is an advise. Provide a summary of the differences, so that anyone reading it doesn't have to look for them on their own. Your answer may solve the problem, but is poorly written. You can edit it to add the above comment for example...

Answer (score 0):

call the onDateSelect instead of selectedClusterDate or customize your backbean.

```java
public void onDateSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");
    format.format(event.getObject());
     //...
}
```

Comment: setting default time for date.Not my selection